# Build highcharts from oracle with html, java, json

Tags: html, json, highcharts

I need to build a chart with highcharts, the data are located in oracle database, y use HTML, java and JavaScript with Json but I have a lot problems the code are:

---

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function () {
            
            var processed_json = new Array();
            var url = "Graficas?Operacion=x";
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                var items = [];
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    alert(value);
                });
            });

            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: "category"
                },
                series: [{
                        data: processed_json
                    }]
            });
        });



    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
</body>
```

---

### Servlet

```
if(request.getParameter("Operacion").equals("x")){
             out.print(operaciones.X());
```

---

### the Java document

```
public JSONObject X() throws SQLException {
        this.status = false;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray arrayObj;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.password);
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select key, value from x");
            stmt.execute();
            rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            arrayObj = new JSONArray();
            while (rs.next()) {
                arrayObj.put(rs.getObject("key").toString());
                arrayObj.put(rs.getObject("value").toString());
            }
            json.put("aaData", arrayObj);
        } catch (Exception x) {
            this.mensajeError = x.getMessage();
            this.status = true;
        } finally {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
            return json;
        }
    }
```

---

I cant build the highcharts, the information are in Oracle, i have to use a Servlet java document and HTML with Json,thanks alot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chart should be inisialised in the $.getJSON() callback because in this case, charts are created before ajax finish. So use this construciton

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: "category"
                },
                series: [{
                        data: data
                    }]
               });
            });
```

Let us know how your json does it look like

Comment: Thanks a lot for help me, I change the code but with that, I think that the problem are when I get the object json look the Java document, are correct???.And look                                var processed_json = new Array();                                      var url = "Graficas?Operacion=x";                                       $.getJSON(url, function (data) { var items = []; $.each(data, function (key, value) { alert(value); }); });                     Is the correct way, because to populate, I know that I need a json object but I get one array from the Java document, thanks

Comment: Honestly Im not familiar with Java, so Im not sure how you can return json form this layer.